# Force AngularJS to reapply a directive on a fresh element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

In one of my project, I have to create a canvas element with some events linked to it. For that reason, I created a directive that takes a context, in that context, I have defined a set of methods that are bound to the element.

- onMouseUp
- onMouseDown
- onTouchMove
- ...

This is working well for one canvas but problems arise when I have to switch between multiple canvas

Here's the template:

```
<canvas ng-if="context" drawing-canvas="context"></canvas>
```

And the directive:

```
mod.directive('drawingCanvas', ['nano', function (nano) {
  function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.drawingCanvas, function (context) {
      var el = element.clone(true)
      element.replaceWith(el)
      element = el

      context.ctx = element[0].getContext("2d")

      //bind events
    })

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  }
}])
```

At first, I didn't have the `replaceWith` part. It is used to create a fresh element without the bound events of the previous contexts. The problem with this method is when I remove a canvas. It seems that AngularJS loose control over the new element and keep it free. I end up with multiple canvas instead of none.

I tried to delete the `context` before switching but it seems that it is happening in the same `digest` and for that reason the context is never falsy and the canvas isn't removed from the view. Is there a nice way to handle my problem?

If there is a way to simply force AngularJS to recreate the canvas, I could probably also remove the `$watch`.